# SQL: Finding Average Score

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, average

[image]

Given the table, I am looking for a query to calculate the average score of a given question for a given teacher.

If I was going to add another column to the table like SCHOOLID and wanted to have a column that calculated the average for a given question for that school, how would I do that?

Thanks in advance for all of your help!

Answer (score 5):

```
select teacherId, questionid, AVG(Score)
From myTable
group by teacherId, questionid
```

Comment: Got it! I thought it was something simple. Do insert this into the table I can just run an update statement like this right:     update #TEST
set AVGSCORE_TEACHER = x.score
from #TEST t
 join (
   select TEACHERID, questionid, score = AVG(Score)
   From #TEST
   group by teacherId, questionid
  )
  x on t.TEACHERID = x.TEACHERID

Comment: For your UPDATE statement you'll want to add:   AND t.questionID = x.questionID  to your join.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stored procedure to handle the whole requirements

```
CREATE PROCEDURE avarageCalc
(
   @teacherid nvarchar(5) = null,
   @questionid int = null,
   @schoolid int = null
)
AS
Begin

    SELECT AVG(SCORE) as Avarage 
                   FROM Table 
                   WHERE (TeacherID = @teacherid OR @teacherid IS NULL) AND 
                         (QuestionId = @questionid OR @questionid IS NULL) AND
                         (SchoolId = @schoolid OR @schoolid IS NULL)

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT TeacherId, QuestionId, AVG(Score)
FROM TABLE-NAME
GROUP BY TeacherId, QuestionId
```

Here are a few links that will help:

1. [3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_avg.asp)
2. [SQL Server - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx)