# SQL query to return average

Tags: sql

I have table `grades`:

```
id | student_id | grade
-----------------------
1  | 1          | 4
2  | 1          | 5
3  | 2          | 3
```

I want a query that returns `student_id` and average `grade`:

```
student_id | avg_grade
----------------------
1          | 4.5
2          | 3
```

What query would do that?

Comment: Did you do any research at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Average of grouped rows in Sql Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100921/average-of-grouped-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Finding Average Score](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098020/sql-finding-average-score)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL's `AVG()` function does that:

```
SELECT student_id, AVG(grade) as avg_grade
FROM grades
GROUP BY student_id
```

[Reference for MySQL's `AVG()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)